# Why does some key figures differ from one annual report to another

Tags: stocks, economics, annual-report

I´ve started to read some annual reports lately and inserted some into my excel sheet to calculate some key figures, but saw that column with "Total assets" differ than reads in the last years report.

```
              2007        2006
TOTAL ASSETS  5,551,614   3,742,338
```

and another year

```
              2008         2007
TOTAL ASSETS  2,781,656    5,262,960
```

2008 Annual Report – ABG Sundal Collier Holding ASA

2007 Annual Report – ABG Sundal Collier Holding ASA

What needs to be taken for the calculation of the various numbers?

Comment: are there any applicable footnotes?

Comment: It looks like Sundal restated its income for the years 2004- 2007 so you should use the restated amounts. This is not a full answer as I can't post my evidence for it - I got it from a commercial source for which I don't have a redistribution license.

Comment: Their annual reports (or perhaps a separate SEC filing in between) should explain the difference)